# How to wrap an element as parent of a known element using GQuery

Tags: jquery, gwt, gquery

Say I have a div as:

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

I have a GQuery object which I got using

```
GQuery mydiv = GQuery.$("#myDiv");
```

Using this, I want to create a new parent which wraps this div element inside it. For example, if the parent is another div, following is what I want:

```
<div id = "parentDiv"> 
   <div id="myDiv"> </div>
</div>
```

Though this sounds like a simple thing to do, I am not able to get the desired result.

Note: I have tagged JQuery for this question as well since if a simple method for the same exists in JQuery, it is probable that it would exist in GQuery as well.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want use [wrap()](http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gwtquery-core/javadoc/com/google/gwt/query/client/GQuery.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29):

```
GQuery mydiv = GQuery.$("#myDiv").wrap('<div id="parentDiv" />');
```

I don't know GQuery, it's based on jQuery.

---

I read some [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Selecting_Content) and I'm not sure if your syntax should be:

```
GQuery mydiv = $("#myDiv").wrap('<div id="parentDiv" />');
```

or something else. Just be sure you have good syntax and use `wrap()`.

Comment: I confirm GQuery mydiv = GQuery.$("#myDiv").wrap("<div id='parentDiv' />"); should work !

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery it is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var parent = $("#myDiv").parent();
$("<div id='parentDiv'></div>").appendTo(parent)
                  $("#myDiv").appendTo($("#parentDiv"));
});​
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/fZ6zx/

Comment: You don't know if `#myDiv` has parent because Saurabh didn't say anything about that. Maybe it's a dynamically created div. Your code in my opinion is triumph of form over content - maybe it would work, but it's not optimal..

Comment: If there is no other parent then <body> is its parent. See the jsFiddle, it works. Though, your solution looks better. Just up voted your answer.

Comment: `body` is a parent when `#myDiv` is present in DOM, but if you use `myDiv = $('<div id="myDiv" />');` and don't append it anywhere, there is no parent.